# Need a hint evaluating $ \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{x\ln{(\frac{\sin (x)}{x})}}{\sin (x) - x} $

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm stuck with this. I've tried substituting $t$ for $\frac{\sin (x)}{x}$ and $\sin (x) - x$ but it doesn't work at all.

A small hint would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\ln{(\frac{\sin (x)}{x})}}{\sin (x) - x} =  \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln{(1+\frac{\sin (x)-x}{x})}}{\frac{\sin (x) - x}{x}} =1 $$ Because $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}-1=1-1=0$$ and $$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}=1.$$

Comment: Woah, it's so elegant. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use the Taylor expansion
$$
\frac{\sin x}{x}=1-\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)
$$
to conclude that
$$
x\ln\frac{\sin x}{x}=-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)
$$
Likewise
$$
\sin x-x=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)-x=-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)
$$
So the limit is $1$.

Comment: We didn't cover Taylor expansion (not even derivatives) yet, but thank you for contribution :)